# App only in Spanish language with PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova

I have a problem building my App with PhoneGap Build. I use version 3.3.0.

My App is only in Spanish language. But when i create my App and install it on my iPhone, some message (like Copy, Paste, Select image...) stay in English language. 
I need this messages stay in Spanish language. 
There have images to see my error.:

```
d2r1vs3d9006ap.cloudfront.net/s3_images/1086847/error1_inline.png

d2r1vs3d9006ap.cloudfront.net/s3_images/1086848/error2_inline.png

d2r1vs3d9006ap.cloudfront.net/s3_images/1086849/error3_inline.png
```

In HTML code I put:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" name="viewport"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0;" /> ...
```

This is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
 xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
 id = "es.dario.app"
 versionCode="10"
 version = "1.0">
 <name>Titulo de la App</name>
 <description>Descipción de la App</description>
 <author href="Dario">Dario</author>
 <content src='login.html'/>
 <access origin="*"/>

 <!-- PREFERENCE -->
 <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />
 <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
 <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
 <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
 <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
 <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
 <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
 <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
 <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
 <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" /> 
 <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
 <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
 <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="white" />
 <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
 <preference name="android-installLocation" value="internalOnly" />
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
 <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xffffff"/>
 <preference name="disable-cursor" value="true" />

 <!-- PLATFORM -->
 <gap:platform name="ios" />
 <gap:platform name="android" />
 <gap:platform name="winphone" />

 <!-- PLUGIN -->
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
 <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" />

 <!-- FEATURE -->
 <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>

 <!-- ICONOS -->
 <icon src="icons/ios/icon57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
 <icon src="icons/ios/icon72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
 <icon src="icons/ios/icon114.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
 <icon src="icons/ios/icon144.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
 <icon src="icons/ios/icon76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
 <icon src="icons/ios/icon120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
 <icon src="icons/ios/icon152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
 <icon src="icons/android/icon36.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
 <icon src="icons/android/icon48.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
 <icon src="icons/android/icon72.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
 <icon src="icons/android/icon-96.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
 <icon src="icons/android/icon144.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
 <icon src="icons/winphone/icon62.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
 <icon src="icons/winphone/icon173.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" />
 <icon src="icon64.png" />

 <!-- SPLASH -->
 <gap:splash src="splash/ios/splash320x480.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/ios/splash480x320.png" gap:platform="ios" width="480" height="320" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/ios/splash640x960.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/ios/splash960x640.png" gap:platform="ios" width="960" height="640" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/ios/splash640x1136.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/ios/splash1136x640.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1136" height="640" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/ios/splash768x1024.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024 " />
 <gap:splash src="splash/ios/splash1024x768.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/ios/splash1536.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/ios/splash2048.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/android/splash240x400.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/android/splash320x480.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/android/splash480x800.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/android/splash720x960.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
 <gap:splash src="splash/winphone/splash480x800.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
 <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

 </widget>
```

To install and run my App ,I downloaded the `.ipa` from Phonegap Build after compiling. 
After connecting to MAC, when I open it using iTunes, double clicked on `.ipa`, of applications (in iTunes) and install it.

Can help me please?
Thanks

Comment: What is the language you use on your device?

Comment: Seems those are messages from the OS, not from the app. To see those in spanish the language of the phone must be in spanish.

Comment: Spanish... all in spanish language...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and looked everywhere on the Internet but couldn't find the answer... After a LOT of thinking I finally figured it out!

I just added this to my config.xml file:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleDevelopmentRegion" overwrite="true">
    <string>French</string>
</gap:config-file>
```

In your case you just need to replace "French" with "Spanish" (or any other language) and it should work! (But I guess it might be a little late for you now...)

(I'm using Phonegap 3.7.0)